# Should I convert all targets to latest Swift syntax?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Xcode 7 Beta automatically selected all my targets for migrating to Swift 2. Is this correct? It seems to me that I should only select my app and test targets.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I needed to also convert Pod targets of other frameworks obviously. This seems like a silly question in retrospect. If I didn't convert the Pod targets, they wouldn't compile with Swift 2. The thing I don't like about it is that I had to modify these other frameworks' source code, but they were just simple syntax changes that should be fine until they officially upgrade.

Answer (score -3):

I don't think Xcode 7 is yet accepted for App Store submissions. So you need to really, really make sure that this fits in with your plans, and keep a Swift 1.2 / Xcode 6 version around in case you need to release an urgent update.

Xcode 7 and Swift 2 are beta software.

Comment: What? I'm completely aware of this and it doesn't even begin to answer my question...

Comment: You can and should make AppStore submissions with the lastest XCode (beta) to opt into features only available when compiled against iOS 9 and to deploy potential fixes.